# What's the link between Planck Mass squared and $1/8πG$?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, quantum-gravity, physical-constants, absolute-units

Good morning,
In an equation of an article, we said that 1/8πG = Mass of Planck^2. But 1/8πG = 596175243.8, is much larger than the Planck Mass^2 = 1.383*10-16 kg. Is there a conversion to do? If not, what is the exact link between the planck mass and 1/8πG? And then after in an equation at the end of the article, it was advanced that s (energy of a proton-proton collision) > Mp. So it is not consistent that Mp^2 = 1/8πG.

Comment: Natural units: $c=1$, $\hbar=1$.

Answer (score 2):

The authors are working in units where $\hbar=c=1$. So you need to insert those factors appropriately until you get something with the mass units that you need.

The particular factor $1/(8\pi)$ is just convention. The mass $1/\sqrt{8\pi G}$ is sometimes called the "reduced Planck mass".

Comment: Thank's a lot!!!

Comment: While not incorrect, if the OP wants SI units, $M_{P}=\sqrt{\hslash c /8 \pi G}$ is the reduced Planck mass